# Windows Phone 7 - App.ViewModel duplicates

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7

```
App.ViewModel.RefreshItems();
lbFruit.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.ItemCollection;
```

I have duplicates in the ItemsCollection.  In my listbox I would only like to show unique values.  How would I just grab those for display?

**I need to show more data here..**.

In my collection I have 1 set of data that could contain duplicates of certain properties in the collection..

In my view model lets say I have fruits and vegetables as properties.

I could have:

ItemCollection[0].fruit = "Apple" 
ItemCollection[0].vegetable="Carrot"

ItemCollection[1].fruit = "Pear" 
ItemColection[1].vegetable="Carrot"

ItemCollection[2].fruit = "Apple" 
itemCollection[2].vegetable = "Green Beans"

If I only want to display the list of fruits in my collection how would I do that without duplication?

For example I could have Multiple Fruits and Multiple Vegetables in my collection.  If I'm only displaying fruits in my list how can I only show: Apple, Pear, Orange

**More Code:**

When I do the distinct as suggested below:
lbFruit.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.ItemCollection.Select(item => item.fruit).Distinct();

I get 2 *'s (the * is my bullet for the list and is found in the TextBlock in the DataTemplate).

So technically the Distinct is working, but the text is not showing up next to the *'s.
As you can see there is also a ProductNumber which I did not show in the original example.  However, when I remove that I still get the same 2 *'s.

**Is there something I need to do on the XAML side to make the distinct work?  Also if I wanted to display the product number how would I add that to the above Select (if we can get it to work)?**

```
           <ListBox x:Name="lbFruit" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" SelectionChanged="lbFruit_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="DataTemplateStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,10">*</TextBlock>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding Fruit}"  FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ItemNumber" Text="{Binding ProductNumber}"  FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Hopefully this all makes sense...  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: use extension method like .Distinct();

Comment: @lukas - I tried that with no luck...  The binding still showed the duplicate values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
lbFruit.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.ItemCollection.Select(item => item.fruit).Distinct();
```

### Edit:

Above code does not work in your case because it returns a list of `String` values and not your items.

To fix that, you need to use `IEqualityComparer<T>` within `Distinct()`.

You have not mentioned your class name or definition so, for following definition,

```
public class ProductItem
{
    public int ProductNumber { get; set; }
    public String Fruit { get; set; }
    public String Vegetable { get; set; }
}
```

You need to create an `IEqualityComparer<ProductItem>` like following:

```
public class ProductItemByFruitComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProductItem>
{
    public bool Equals(ProductItem x, ProductItem y)
    {
        // Case-insensitive comparison of Fruit property of both objects evaluates equality between them
        return x.Fruit.Equals(y.Fruit, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ProductItem obj)
    {
        // Since we are using Fruit property to compare two ProductItems, we return Fruit's HashCode in this method
        return obj.Fruit.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then, the following statement should do the trick:

```
lbFruit.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.ItemCollection.Distinct(new ProductItemByFruitComparer());
```

Comment: When I do this the binding doesn't occur or atleast the text from the ItemCollection doesn't show up (in the Listbox).  Any ideas?

Comment: I added more code to see maybe if I needed to do something differently in the xaml...

Comment: !  you rock!  That worked like a champ...  Just out of curiosity...  If I wanted to further explore how you came up with this solution, is there some sites that I could look at to see what the HashCode is and why you used it?  Or more info on the IEqualityComparer?  I don't want to just ask these questions without trying to understand them better.  Thanks again!